# MYSQL Auto Arrange the id when one row is delete, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a table:
Employee is auto increment

```
Employee ID | First Name
1           | Chong
2           | Dan
3           | RJ
4           | Joshua
```

when I delete the row where employee_id = 2, it shows this

```
Employee ID | First Name
1           | Chong
3           | RJ
4           | Joshua
```

what I want is to have something like this

```
    Employee ID | First Name
1           | Chong
2           | RJ
3           | Joshua
```

then when I add another row, for example, I add steve

```
Employee ID | First Name
1           | Chong
2           | RJ
3           | Joshua
4           | Steve
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-sorting id column in a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382060/re-sorting-id-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Please don't do it.

Comment: @shmosel ok hahahaha

Comment: @shmosel how about if i add? It will automatically assign to free id slot, for example in my case, when i add steve, it will be automatically assigned to id2, is it ok like that?

Comment: @Chong it's fine to take an empty slot if you're adding a new row. Though I still don't see value in that. They're just row identifiers, it shouldn't matter if they're sequential or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using update in the trigger if you want to

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `tableName` SET `tableName`.`employeeId` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: You'll only encourage him

Comment: @shmosel its not good idea I know but he want to know how. I guess